# In MVC error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Morvel.DLL"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stack-overflow

I m using MVC architecture in ASP.NET 3.5. In edit I'm getting the above error.

1) I have used stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[editparty]

    (
    @pcode nvarchar(50),

    @cname nvarchar(100),

    @cont  nvarchar(50)
    )
AS


update tbl_party set party_name=@cname,party_code = @pcode,party_contact =@cont where party_id=(Select party_id  from tbl_party where party_code = @pcode)
```

2) This is my function in DAL class file:

```
public DataSet editp(BOParty pcode, BOParty PName, BOParty Tel)
        {
            OpenCnn();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("editparty", cnn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter[] par = { new SqlParameter("@pcode", pcode.pcode), };
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(par);
            SqlParameter[] nm = { new SqlParameter("@PName", pcode.pcode), };
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(nm);
            SqlParameter[] tl = { new SqlParameter("@Tel", pcode.pcode), };
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(tl);
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
            CloseCnn();


        }
```

3)this in in BAL class file

```
    public DataSet editp(BOParty pcode, BOParty PName, BOParty Tel)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds = editp(pcode, PName, Tel);
        return ds;
    }
```

4) This is in .cs file:

```
    protected void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pcode.pcode = txtpcde.Text;
        pcode.Tel= txtcont.Text;
        pcode.PName = txtcname.Text;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds = pcode.editp(pcode, PName, Tel);

        edit.Enabled = false;

    }
```

Comment: okay i got my answer, i dint use object of dal class for calling the function in bal class file--- http://stackoverflow.com/a/11225083/1445836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look your `editp` function at the highlighted line:

```
public DataSet editp(BOParty pcode, BOParty PName, BOParty Tel)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = new DataSet();
    ds = editp(pcode, PName, Tel); // <--- HERE
    return ds;
}
```

You call `editp` recursively then it'll cause `StackOverflowException`. I think you would like to call `editp` method in the DAL class but there you're calling the same `editp` method again and again.

Comment: @Zoya you should post **even more** code, `editp` in DAL class isn't static so you need an instance of that class inside your BAL class. Do you have it? Manage to have that instance then simply call `_instanceOfDalClass.editp(pcode, PName, Tel);`.

Comment: okay i got my answer, i dint use object of dal class for calling the function in bal class file

Comment: @Zoya oh for _my_ `StackOverflowException`s I did worse, do not worry! LOL

Answer (score 0):

3)this in in BAL class file

```
  public DataSet editp(BOParty pcode, BOParty PName, BOParty Tel)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds = party.editp(pcode, PName, Tel);<------ party is object of DAL class file( private     DAParty partydata;)--------------


        return ds;
    }
```